# How to recreate database in EF if my model changes?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I created a DbContext like so :

```
   public class myDB : DbContext
   {
     public DbSet<Party> Parties { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
   }
```

This generated my DataBase and the two tables above..Great

I then decided to add another DbSet into the mix & I got an error:

> the model backing the 'Party' context has changed since the database was created

I'm aware of the fixes for this using `modelbuilder.IncludeMetadataInDatabase = false;` and `Database.SetInitializer<ClubmansGuideDB>(null);`

1) What's the correct way to add my new classes to the context and have them generated in the DataBase?

2) In my futile attempts to solve this myself I deleted the tables and tried to re-run the app with no success I then deleted the full database and re-run and it doesn't re-generate the DB. How can I start from scratch - is there some cache somewhere?

Comment: **entity framework issue** isn't the best title I have ever seen.

Comment: What use is that comment, when so many good answers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you're looking for:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ClubmansGuideDB>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ClubmansGuideDB>());
```

As of EF 4.1 and above.

Note that this assumes you have permission to even drop your database. I do this locally for ease of development but disable it in staging/production (I do a manual Schema Compare and push my changes).

By the way, for testing, if you need to force recreate the database, you can do:

```
using (var context = new ClubmansGuideDB()) {
    context.Database.Initialize(force: true);
}
```

(`using` if you don't already have a reference to your DB)

Comment: Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDbContext>());
Database.Initialize(true); why not work form me??

Answer (score 3):

You can let the Entity Framework recreate the whole database by using a `Database Initializer` or if you want to migrate data you can look at the [Code First Migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/29/code-first-migrations-beta-1-released.aspx)

The following would recreate your database when the model changes:

```
Database.SetInitializer<myDB>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<myDB>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your Global.asax.cs  Application_Start() method.

```
Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
```

To reset the database from scratch on app run make a class like this

```
//Where myDB is your context
public class EntityBase: DropCreateDatabaseAlways<myDB>
{

}
```

Then in your Application_Start() method you can do this

```
Database.SetInitializer(new EntityBase());
```

Comment: you can also override the Seed method and fill your database with test data. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679212(v=vs.103).aspx