# Entity Framework: Drop database if application is reinstalled

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

Is it possible to drop the application's database if the application is reinstalled?

EDIT:
The client wants the database to be "purged" every time a new version of the application is installed. DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges won't cut it because they might install/reinstall the application without changes in the model.

Comment: can you made this quesion more specific, and describe what you need ?

Comment: What do you mean by reinstall ? if the model has changed ?

Comment: Need some more insight. Why do you want to drop the db ? you will lose previous data. Think about an app upgrade. It would be too costly to drop the db right ;)

Comment: Don´t drop data in a working envireonment, even if the data-model changes. YOu should create some migration-software to migrate existing data from one model to the newer one.

Comment: @TusharGupta it could be usefull for dev purpose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recreate database in EF if my model changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793184/how-to-recreate-database-in-ef-if-my-model-changes)

Comment: We have developed a WPF app. The users want to drop all the data whenever they install a new version or reinstall the current version.

Comment: That's the client's requirements. We tried talking them out of it. DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges won't work since they may reinstall/install the app without any changes in the model.

Answer (score 1):

If you use some setup program (MSI, for example) you need add custom actions on Update, Unistall or Re-install events that deletes the database.

Other solution is to add it to the main code:

```
if (IsVersionChanged()) {

    if (Database.Exists(...)) { Database.Drop(...); }
}
```

But it does not address the Re-Install case (you may try to detect this case by analyzing a file timestamp that should be always overwritten on installation/re-installation but it is only worth doing if you don't have a setup program).

There're several ways how you can implement the IsVersionChanged. For example, you can keep the version in the database itself or keep the last version in the windows registry.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Database SetInitializer static member with desired parameter. Sample for Create if there is no db.

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext 
    {

        public YourDbContext (): base("yourConnectionString") 
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<YourDbContext>());
        }  
    }
```