# Map model to existing database table using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I face some difficulties when attempt to map my class to existing table using Entity Framework. I currently using Code first but a table was created without it and i cannot map it to a model a created.

My class:

```
 [Table("AgentCallsByPartner")]
public class AgentCallsByPartnerModel
{
    [Key]
    public int AgentCallID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CallDate { get; set; }

    public string CustomerID { get; set; }

    public string AgentNo { get; set; }

    public string AccountCreated { get; set; }

    public string QuoteStarted { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GroupRollup { get; set; }

}
```

Context

```
    public DbSet<AgentCallsByPartnerModel> AgentCallsByPartner { get; set; }
```

And this is my table

[image]

But when I try to get users from the database, I get an exception

DbContext has changed since the database was created....

So what is my mistake? Thanks

Comment: did you update your migration ? did you apply  drop create new database if mode change ?

Comment: i did not since table was created directly in sql server, do i need to do something?

Comment: Do you  have any idea migration?

Comment: check my answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can be perform several way i just describe few way

From the Tools menu, click `Library Package Manager` and then `Package Manager Console`.

The `enable-migrations` command creates a Migrations folder in the your project, and it puts in that folder a Configuration.cs file that you can edit to configure Migrations.

(If you missed the step above that directs you to change the database name, Migrations will find the existing database and automatically do the `add-migration` command. That's OK, it just means you won't run a test of the migrations code before you deploy the database. Later when you run the `update-database` command nothing will happen because the database will already exist.)

more detail migration http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/801545/Code-First-Migrations-With-Entity-Framework

another way :

[How to recreate database in EF if my model changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793184/how-to-recreate-database-in-ef-if-my-model-changes)

Note: if you use migration then do not lose data value most of time

### Update:

problem in migration process run the flowing command

> Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges
>
> Update-Database -verbose

Comment: I ran the add-migration command, them update-databse, it throw a message in red saying There is already an object named 'AgentCallsByPartner' in the database.

Comment: try with this blog ...  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/801545/Code-First-Migrations-With-Entity-Framework