# Database not created automatically

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created an ASP.NET MVC 4 project. I know that by just by having a `DbContext` derived class, if I instantiate this class such as:

```
MyContextDb _db = new MyContextDb();
```

and ask it for data, it is supposed to go out and see if a database exist. And if that database doesn't exist, it is supposed to be created for me.

However, I am testing this theory and it doesn't work. I have a property in my `MyDbContext` class:

```
public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
```

and for this property I have a class in my `Models` folder:

```
public class Restaurant
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

This is part of a tutorial I found on the internet. I build the project (by the way I have Entity Framework 6.1.3 and SQL Server 2016 Express version) and the error that I get is:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

Here is my connection string, added to the `web.config` file inside the configuration section:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\v13.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-mydb-20170527102515;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-mydb-20170527102515.mdf" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Not sure what else to try. I am able to access SQL Server by localhost (or dot) and no credentials, through Windows authentication and I have set SQL Server to allow remote connections and to allow mixed mode authentication (either through credentials or through Windows). Any thoughts on this? Pretty common situation but nothing I've tried seems to have helped so far.

I also tried the UDL trick (save a file with .udl extension, double click it, enter parameters to connect in the small dialogue interface and after you successfully test the connection, then open the udl as text, something like this showed up:

```
<add name="Def" 
     connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=anotherDb;Data Source=."/>
```

Then I replaced `anotherDb` in the `web.config` with my desired database name, hoping it would be created by ASP.NET but NO.)

What else should I try?

===========

I got it to work by adding this to the web.config

```
 <add name="connStr" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\mvcpath\begin\course1\MyProj\App_Data\Database123.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and this piece as a constructor:

```
public MyContextDb() : base("connStr")
{
    Database.SetInitializer<MyContextDb>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContextDb>());
}
```

Comment: Well since you don't create the database everyday, just create the db yourself. Otherwise if you are looking to drop and recreate database when context changes, you can use DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793184/how-to-recreate-database-in-ef-if-my-model-changes

Comment: Your issue, as stated in the exception, is related to the connection to SQL Server. Install SQL Server or fix the connection string and you'll see that the database and the tables will be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework is not supposed to and it will never create a database for you unless you explicitly ask it to create one for you if it doesn't exist.

You need to add this to your context's constructor code:

```
if (!Database.Exists())
{
    Database.Create();
}
```

Or you can use a Database Initialization Strategy that suits you, like:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContextDb>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContextDb>());
```

Comment: In the controller, Camilo? In any special method?

Comment: @Halle you can do that in the DbContext's constructor

Comment: @Halle can you edit your question and add how you are passing the connection string to EF?

Comment: That´s not true you can configure and use a database initializer: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much Camilo and k7s5a for pointing me in the direction of database initializers. It didn't work until I added that and also the conn string name in the ctor as a parameter. Much appreciated!

Comment: @k7s5a what is not true? A Database initializer is exactly what I said: you need to **opt in**

Comment: Maybe k7s5a was referring to what I initially thought: that the db can be autogenerated without initializer. My mistake (I removed that comment to avoid misleading people). I have been working with multiple variants of this project so I must have got confused. Btw interesting to know that the initializer can exist also in a config file (as seen in the link from k7s5a). Thank you both! I added the solution to the bottom of the original post

Comment: One can add that in anything except the most trivial and simplified use case, generating the database wll NOT happen in the application. Initializing it may (bad style also for anything serious), but normal users will NOT have the right to allocate space on decent company database server. Database maintenance normally should involve some planning step, if anything to make sure backups are in place. Examples? Sharepoint, TFS etc. - all do NOT magically go out and put your files "somewhere".

Comment: @TomTom exactly. Users do not have CREATE DATABASE permissions in serious companies, so EF should not even try to do it. However, it does help a lot during development

Answer (score 0):

Something is not clear in the accepted answer here.

In *SchoolContext.cs*

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.DAL
{
    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {

        public SchoolContext() : base("SchoolContext")
        {
        }
   }
}
```

in *Web.config*

```
<contexts>
      <context type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext, ContosoUniversity">
        <databaseInitializer type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolInitializer, ContosoUniversity" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
```

Then custom initialiser *SchoolInitializer.cs*

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.DAL
{
    public class SchoolInitializer : System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SchoolContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(SchoolContext context)
        {
            ....
         }
}
```

This is the way you should consider at all.

Alternatively, you can use code first migration. In this case, you have to comment your initializer in the context. Code first will use Seed method after each ***update-database*** statement from the package manager.

In *configuration.cs* (from the migrations folder).

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.Migrations
{
    using ContosoUniversity.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext context)
        {
            var students = new List<Student>
            {
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Carson",   LastName = "Alexander",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2010-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Meredith", LastName = "Alonso",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Arturo",   LastName = "Anand",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Gytis",    LastName = "Barzdukas",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Yan",      LastName = "Li",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Peggy",    LastName = "Justice",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2011-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Laura",    LastName = "Norman",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-09-01") },
                new Student { FirstMidName = "Nino",     LastName = "Olivetto",
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2005-08-11") }
            };
            students.ForEach(s => context.Students.AddOrUpdate(p => p.LastName, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var courses = new List<Course>
            {
                new Course {CourseID = 1050, Title = "Chemistry",      Credits = 3, },
                new Course {CourseID = 4022, Title = "Microeconomics", Credits = 3, },
                new Course {CourseID = 4041, Title = "Macroeconomics", Credits = 3, },
                new Course {CourseID = 1045, Title = "Calculus",       Credits = 4, },
                new Course {CourseID = 3141, Title = "Trigonometry",   Credits = 4, },
                new Course {CourseID = 2021, Title = "Composition",    Credits = 3, },
                new Course {CourseID = 2042, Title = "Literature",     Credits = 4, }
            };
            courses.ForEach(s => context.Courses.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Title, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var enrollments = new List<Enrollment>
            {
                new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alexander").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Chemistry" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.A
                },
                 new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alexander").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Microeconomics" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.C
                 },
                 new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alexander").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Macroeconomics" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                 },
                 new Enrollment {
                     StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alonso").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Calculus" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                 },
                 new Enrollment {
                     StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alonso").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Trigonometry" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                 },
                 new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Alonso").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Composition" ).CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                 },
                 new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Anand").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Chemistry" ).CourseID
                 },
                 new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Anand").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Microeconomics").CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                 },
                new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Barzdukas").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Chemistry").CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                 },
                 new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Li").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Composition").CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                 },
                 new Enrollment {
                    StudentID = students.Single(s => s.LastName == "Justice").ID,
                    CourseID = courses.Single(c => c.Title == "Literature").CourseID,
                    Grade = Grade.B
                 }
            };

            foreach (Enrollment e in enrollments)
            {
                var enrollmentInDataBase = context.Enrollments.Where(
                    s =>
                         s.Student.ID == e.StudentID &&
                         s.Course.CourseID == e.CourseID).SingleOrDefault();
                if (enrollmentInDataBase == null)
                {
                    context.Enrollments.Add(e);
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```